# How to merge two dictionaries in a specific way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a two dictionaries like:

```
d1 = {'new_list1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'new_list2':['a', 'b', 'd', 'e']}
d2 = {'new_list1': [1,2,3,4], 'new_list2': [1,2,4,5]}
```

I want output like:

```
d3 = {'new_list1':[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4]], 'new_list2':[['a',1],['b',2],['d',4],['e',5]]}
```

Points to See:
1. both the dictionaries will have same number of keys
2. values present in form of list can have different length, so padding as 0 will be required in case of mismatch

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The `new_list2` of `d1` and `d2` looks broken.

Comment: @BlackThunder I did that using a long method, parsing individually and append, need some optimized solution as data is big

Comment: the elements "new_list1, new_list2, etc" inside the 2 list are always the same or they can be different?

Comment: @Carlo1585 it can be different

Comment: but the number of elements inside the "new_list1" of d1 and d2 is always the same? otherwise u need a rule to decide what to put together

Comment: @Dhiraj: there are some "gaps" here in the problem statement. What should happen if a key is missing in the other dictionary? What should happen if the lists have a different length? Can you please update your question, and make sure you fix these questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
d3 = dict(zip(d1.keys(),[list(zip(d1[k], d2[k])) for k in d1]))
```

**Output** :

```
{'new_list1': [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)], 'new_list2': [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]}
```

Answer (score 3):

If possible match each value between both lists of dictionaries use:

```
out = {k:list(map(list, zip(v, d2[k]))) for k, v in d1.items()}
print (out)
{'new_list1': [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4]], 
 'new_list2': [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['d', 4], ['e', 5]]}
```

If lengths not match use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from  itertools import zip_longest

d1 = {'new_list1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'new_list2':['a', 'b']}
d2 = {'new_list1': [1,2,3], 'new_list2': [1,2,4,5]}

out = {k:list(map(list, zip_longest(v, d2[k], fillvalue=0))) for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Or:

```
out = {k: list(map(list, zip_longest(d1[k], d2[k], fillvalue=0))) for k in d1}
print (out)
{'new_list1': [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 0]], 
 'new_list2': [['a', 1], ['b', 2], [0, 4], [0, 5]]}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the answer below. Any issues with it.?

Comment: @AlbinAntony - It depends of python version, if use `python 3` then get `{'new_list1': <map object at 0x000000000C39CC18>, 'new_list2': <map object at 0x0000000006D70B00>}`

Answer (score 3):

An update to @jezrael answer. I don't think there is any need to typecast the result of map to a list.

```
from  itertools import zip_longest

d1 = {'new_list1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'new_list2':['a', 'b']}
d2 = {'new_list1': [1,2,3], 'new_list2': [1,2,4,5]}

out = {k:map(list, zip_longest(v, d2[k], fillvalue=0)) for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Or:

```
out = {k: map(list, zip_longest(d1[k], d2[k], fillvalue=0)) for k in d1}
print (out)
{'new_list1': [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 0]], 
 'new_list2': [['a', 1], ['b', 2], [0, 4], [0, 5]]}
```